# Convex hull that ignores sets of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

In my research I use a definition of convex hull that is compatible with measure theory, in the sense that it ignores negligible sets.

Are there any references to the following concept, or similar concepts, in the literature? (The name, obviously, need not be the same.)

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, $d \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Define the **closed essential convex hull** of $A$ as the intersection of all half-spaces $H \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ that satisfy
\begin{equation}
m(A \setminus H) = 0,
\end{equation}
where $m$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I don't believe I've seen this notion, but a google search for ["essential boundary" "Giorgi" "convex hull"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22essential+boundary%22+%22Giorgi%22+%22convex+hull%22) might lead to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were unable to find anything in the literature, so now some basic facts can be found in the preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02814 .